# Using jQuery &/or CSS to enlarge image when hovering AND staying large selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to use jQuery or css so that I can select one of 3 images and

1. when I hover, the image enlarges
2. when I select an image, it stays enlarged

I have the following code below. I'm not using HTML5 unfortunately. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="editList" value="general"><img src="images/debit_general.png" />

            <input type="radio" name="editList" value="plane"><img src="images/debit_plane.png" />

            <input type="radio" name="editList" value="robot"><img src="images/debit_robot.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    alert($("#editList").val);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: And at what point did you get stuck when you were composing your code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you could do. I am transforming the scale on hover and when its checked, but if you run into issues with other images covering other input fields you could use width.

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');

for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i ++){
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function(e){
    if(e.currentTarget.checked){
      e.currentTarget.parentNode.className = 'selected';
    } else{
      e.currentTarget.parentNode.className = '';
    }
  });
}
```

```css
label img{
  width: 50px;
  transition: 1s transform;
  transform-origin: 0;
}
label:hover img{
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
.selected img{
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
</label>
```

Comment: Good, but you don't need the javascript. Just use CSS      input:checked ~ img { transform: scale(1.5); }